# How to export schemas from oracle 11g(linux) to windows(19c) using Datapump

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle19c, datapump

I am using Oracle 11.2.0.3 version in linux environment i want to import my schemas to oracle 19c windows.

I am using below commands

Exported from - schemas in Linux =oracle 11.2.0.3

```
expdp username/pwd DUMPFILE=file.dmp LOGFILE=file.log DIRECTORY=TEMPDIR SCHEMAS=A,B,C,D,E
```

And imported schemas in windows =oracle 19c

```
impdp username/pwd DUMPFILE=file.dmp LOGFILE=file.log DIRECTORY=TEMPDIR DIRECTORY=NEW FULL=y
```

Two ora errors i got

```
ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"schema"."table" failed to create with error:
ORA-00904: "SYS_STSX8$DPRIW_E8FERF4S_57KS3": invalid identifier
```

Let me know any thing i need to change in while taking IMPDP

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, when using data pump between two different database versions, you should

- perform export using source Export Data Pump utility (11g in your case)
- perform import using target Import Data Pump utility (19c in your case)

Did you do that?

For **much more info**, read Doc ID 553337.1 on My Oracle Support (quite a lengthy document, but it should answer all questions you might have).